# Working with both old and new URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use both my old and new url for my site. Recently i have converted to MVC with php. After converting to MVC my old url are not working. But if anyone wants to access the old url, i want he can access the old one. My new urls are like

```
www.mysite.com/default.php?controller=dashboard
```

I have changed this ugly url by htaccess. Now the display of my new url is like

```
www.mysite.com/dashboard
```

And for this i write the following htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ./default.php?controller=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ ./default.php?controller=$1
```

Now problem is that my old url was like

```
www.mysite.com/dashboard.php
```

If anyone tries this type of url with .php ext, this occurs "Error 404". How can both url be accessed like

```
www.mysite.com/dashboard
www.mysite.com/dashboard.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just tweak regex in your rule and replace 2 rules with this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(?:\.php)?/?$ default.php?controller=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```